# Error in Windshaft-cartodb installation step of CartoDb

Tags: carto, mapnik, windshaft

I am trying to install cartodb on ubuntu 12.04. I have done all the steps mentioned on https://github.com/CartoDB/cartodb and I am stuck at the *Install Windshaft-cartodb Step*. 
The following steps worked fine:

```
git clone git://github.com/CartoDB/Windshaft-cartodb.git
cd Windshaft-cartodb
git checkout master
npm install
cp config/environments/development.js.example config/environments/development.js
```

Whenever I hit the command node app.js development, it gives me following error:

> module.js:340
>   throw err;
>   ^
>   Error: Cannot find module 'mapnik'
>   at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
>   at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
>   at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
>   at require (module.js:380:17)
>   at Object. (/home/indictrans/Documents/Windshaft-cartodb/node_modules/windshaft/lib/windshaft/server.js:8:21)
>   at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
>   at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
>   at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
>   at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
>   at Module.require (module.js:364:17)

I installed mapnik using `sudo apt-get install libmapnik libmapnik-dev mapnik-utils python-mapnik`. I also tried `npm install mapnik`but the problem still persists.

I have googled lot on this issue but each time it gave the same solution.
I have also installed TileMill to map Mapnik dependecy but it is not working.

Answer (score 1):

Judging from the error output you get the error is not with the system install of mapnik, but with the node dependency windshaft:

The source of the failing file:
`/home/indictrans/Documents/Windshaft-cartodb/node_modules/windshaft/lib/windshaft/server.js:8:21`

has the following line:

`, mapnik      = require('mapnik')`

Since this require fails for you it indicates that the windshaft's dependencies did not get install properly on the `npm install` command. The directory `./node_modules/windshaft/node_modules/mapnik/` should contain the mapnik node module files if everything went fine.

If I were you I would try to delete the `./node_modules` directory and do a `npm install` again, make sure to use the required node version (v0.10).